# Logstash current date logstash.conf as backup_add_prefix (s3 input plugin)

Tags: amazon-s3, logstash

I want to add the current date to every filename that is incoming to my s3 bucket.

My current config looks like this:

```
input {
  s3 {
    access_key_id => "some_key"
    secret_access_key => "some_access_key"
    region => "some_region"
    bucket => "mybucket"
    interval => "10"
    sincedb_path => "/tmp/sincedb_something"
    backup_add_prefix =>'%{+yyyy.MM.dd.HH}'
    backup_to_bucket => "mybucket"
    additional_settings => {
      force_path_style => true
      follow_redirects => false
                }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to use the current date in backup_add_prefix =>'%{+yyyy.MM.dd.HH}'
because the current syntax does not work as it produces: "
%{+yyyy.MM.dd.HH}test_file.txt" in my bucket.

Answer (score 0):

Though it's not supported in s3 input plugin directly, it can be achieved. Use the following steps:

1. Go to logstash home path.
2. Open the file **vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-input-s3-3.4.1/lib/logstash/inputs/s3.rb**. The exact path will depend on your lagstash version.
3. Look for the method **backup_to_bucket**.
4. There is a line **backup_key = "#{@backup_add_prefix}#{object.key}"**
5. Add following lines before the above line:

   `t = Time.new
   date_s3 = t.strftime("%Y.%m.%d")`
6. Now change the **backup_key** to **#{@backup_add_prefix}#{date_s3}#{object.key}**

Now you are done. Restart your logstash pipeline. It should be able to achieve the desired result.